# Why does Overriding Gtk.Widget.OnActivate() Change the Behaviour of the Widget?

Tags: .net, mono, widget, overriding, gtk#

I am trying to derive a class from [`Gtk.Button`](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aGtk.Button). I have encountered an obstacle that I can work around (by not using `OnActivate` at all), but that I cannot explain, hence working around it may be unsafe.

It seems that overriding the [`OnActivate` method](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aGtk.Widget.OnActivate%28%29) that `Gtk.Button` inherits from `Gtk.Widget` changes the behaviour of the button.

**Why is that, and how can I prevent it?**

The only way to even achieve such an effect involves some ugly reflection-based checking.

---

Here's exactly what I did, and what you can try in order to reproduce the issue:

This is a small sample Gtk# application that contains a custom button class and one instance of that class. `OnActivate` is not overridden in the custom button class.

```
using System;

using Gtk;

namespace ButtonOnActivateExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private class MyButton : Button
        {
            public MyButton()
            {
            }

            public MyButton(IntPtr raw)
            {
            }
        }

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init();
            using (Window win = new Window("OnActivate Test")) {
                win.SetSizeRequest(300, 200);
                win.Hidden += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                    Application.Quit();
                };

                MyButton btn = new MyButton();
                btn.Clicked += delegate {
                    Console.WriteLine("clicked");
                };
                win.Add(btn);

                win.ShowAll();
                Application.Run();
                win.Destroy();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, the word *clicked* will be added in a new line in the console. If the button is focused (which usually is the case, as it is the only focusable element in the window), and the user presses the space bar, the same happens, as expected (i.e. the [`Clicked` event](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=E%3aGtk.Button.Clicked) is fired).

---

In this modified version, there is a slight alteration: The `MyButton` class now overrides the `OnActivate` method, but the overridden version does nothing beside calling the inherited version of the method:

```
using System;

using Gtk;

namespace ButtonOnActivateExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private class MyButton : Button
        {
            public MyButton()
            {
            }

            public MyButton(IntPtr raw)
            {
            }

            protected override void OnActivate()
            {
                base.OnActivate();
            }
        }

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init();
            using (Window win = new Window("OnActivate Test")) {
                win.SetSizeRequest(300, 200);
                win.Hidden += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                    Application.Quit();
                };

                MyButton btn = new MyButton();
                btn.Clicked += delegate {
                    Console.WriteLine("clicked");
                };
                win.Add(btn);

                win.ShowAll();
                Application.Run();
                win.Destroy();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should be semantically the same as the first version. Yet, it is not - inexplicably, the behaviour of the application has changed!

The [docs](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aGtk.Widget.OnActivate%28%29) just say about `OnActivate`: "Override this method in a subclass to be notified when the widget is activated, commonly when the user presses Enter or Space during key navigation."

Clicking the button still fires the `Clicked` event. However, pressing the space bar has no effect any more; nothing appears in the console.

I could consistently reproduce this behaviour with Gtk# for .NET, Mono on Windows 7 and Mono on Ubuntu.

**What is going on here?**

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question. Unfortunately I can't give a definitive answer about the precise cause. Even though I have looked into the gtk# source I was quickly lost in the jungle of default signal handlers, klasses and gtypes.

If you are just looking for the solution, though, I can tell you that: you should be overriding the `OnActivated` method (with a `d` at the end).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (+1); unfortunately, I am not looking for the "solution" on how to override `OnActivate` (I'm not even sure what I'd want to override it for), but I'm indeed looking for the cause of, or an explanation for this behaviour. Unless I can find it, I'll be wary of overriding *anything* in `Gtk.Widget` subclasses for fear of unknowingly breaking something where there *shouldn't* be any semantic change to the program :-/